# Multiple groupings in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a search form for users in my mongo database having this structure

```
[
    { _id: 45aba8a34a8a,
      name: blabla,
      country: france,
      region: alsace
     },
     { _id: 6ccbef3a4a83,
      name: blabla,
      country: germany,
      region: hessen
     }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get a list of possible countries and regions in the database. I can partly achieve this by the following code

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$country"
        }
    }
], function (err, res) {
    ...
});
```

However this will only give me the grouped countries and not regions. Is there a way to do this in a single aggregation? I guess the ideal result would be something like

```
{
    countries: [ 'france', 'germany', ... ],
    regions: [ 'alsace', 'hessen', ...]
}
```

But I haven't been able to find how to obtain this anywhere on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like below.

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { country: "$country", region: "$region" }
        }
    }
], function (err, res) {
    ...
});
```

You may look at [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet) in case you need distinct records.

Comment: Hmm.. Doing this will give me multiple countries and regions. I was hoping they could be distinct

Comment: Look at this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/ It might give you some idea.